# Nuget pack fails when using $id$

Tags: nuget, csproj, nuspec

I tried this in 2 different projects already -
I have a nuspec file with $id$ replacement token but the 'nuget pack' command fails on error 1.
When I remove that specific replacement token, while still using the others, the 'nuget pack' command succeeds.

I read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#Replacement_Tokens) that the id is taken from the csproj's AssemblyName property, which I checked at my project files and it seems legit (no spaces etc.)

I'm kinda lost here...
Any idea?

This is the nuspec file

Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>   
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <copyright>Copyright 2020</copyright>
    <dependencies />
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="*.*" target="lib\net45\" exclude="*.pdb;*.nupkg;*.vshost.*"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should have read the manual, some replacement token are only accessible when packing the csproj file and not the nuspec file.